# Why is assignment to a mutable variable illegal in rust while a shared reference to it exists?

Tags: rust

```
let mut x;
x = 42;
let y = &x;
x = 43;
assert_eq!(*y, 42);
```

Why does it matter if x is assigned to while there is a reference to it in y? These are copy-able values. Does the address of x on the stack become invalidated with the assignment so that x is now a new location on the stack and y could be a dangling reference to the old x? Otherwise, if x has it's value overwritten, the reference to it is still valid.

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `x` because it is borrowed
  --> src\main.rs:17:5
   |
16 |     let y = &x;
   |             -- borrow of `x` occurs here
17 |     x = 43;
   |     ^^^^^^ assignment to borrowed `x` occurs here
18 |     assert_eq!(*y, 42);
   |     ------------------ borrow later used here
```

Comment: Because you potentially changed the in memory address of `x`, so `y` could be a dangling reference. If you did `let y = x` you would copy `x` into `y`, and then `y == 42`. In short: references *never* copy.

Comment: That's the only reason I could figure why this would not be allowed. So in Rust, a mutable variable (x) isn't guaranteed to have the same memory address if it is reassigned to? Are these technicalities documented somewhere? I assumed that x would still have the same memory address on the stack and would just be overwritten with the new value.

Comment: @MeetTitan's argument is probably easier to understand with a different example: `let mut x = vec![1,2,3]; let y = &x[2]; x = vec![1,2];`. I think other reason is that "If you have a const reference to something, it won't change while that reference exists" is a strong guarantee to the compiler for optimizations, and to humans who are trying to understand some code.

Comment: Imagine you have 100 lines of code between the definition of `y` and the reassignment of `x`, and then 100 lines later you use `y` again. Would you really want to track down why `y` is changing out from under you? If you want to modify `y`, just... modify `y`. You have the mutable reference.

Comment: You refer specifically to `Copy` types. Is your question only why these rules apply to `Copy` types also?

Comment: @Caesar's example makes perfect sense for references to values on the heap and you get the standard dangling reference and possible excess deallocation. I guess it's not a question about Copy types per se, but about references to values on the stack. (By the way, the example code was taken from the book "Rust for Rustaceans".) I can't seem to find any issue with this example since it would seem to me that the same memory "slot" is simply overwritten. Is it such that the Rust borrow checker doesn't care to distinguish this case?

Comment: @HAA: I could have also made an example with an enum on the stack, say `enum X {A(u8), B(bool)}`. If you'd keep a ref to `B.0`, you could get a `bool` with an invalid value, which is [UB](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html).

Comment: You can actually have some [good fun](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=a979c59f9eba582ab975f1d12d1eacec) with that enums like that. If `D` was a `&T`, things would be catastrophic levels of fun.

Comment: @Caeser Ah, yes I see now. The enum is a type that could cause such disaster since they can hold data of varying lengths. I guess also structs with references can also become problematic.